# JPA update one to one association object leads to duplicate entry exception

Tags: jsf, jpa

I am using JSF 2.0, Tomcat 7.x and EclipseLink as JPA-Provider. I want to update an entity instance with a onetoone association, more precisely a Booking got a User property named booker. Unfortunately if I invoke my updateBooking() Api-method, EclipseLink want to create a new booker instead of just using the already exisiting user. Eclipse console stacktrace and relevant code snippets are added - thanks in advance for some hints!

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'EMAIL'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO user (EMAIL, NAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: WriteObjectQuery(LogString User - id: 1; name: 1; email: 1;)
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'EMAIL'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

DevelopmentController.java

```
public String testUpdateBooking(){
    String str = "/development.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    try {
        Integer bookingId = 22;
        Integer bookerId = 1;
        BookerApi api = new BookerApi();
        Booking booking = api.readBooking(bookingId);
        User booker = api.readUser(bookerId);
        booking.setBooker(booker);
        api.updateBooking(booking);
        message = "DevelopmentController.testUpdateBooking() " + booking;
    } catch (RuntimeException exc){
        message = "EXCEPTION DevelopmentController.testUpdateBooking();"; 
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

BookerApi.java

```
public void updateBooking(Booking booking){
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Booking persBooking = em.find(Booking.class, booking.getId());
    persBooking.setCourtNo(booking.getCourtNo());
    persBooking.setStart(booking.getStart());
    persBooking.setEnd(booking.getEnd());
    persBooking.setBooker(booking.getBooker());
    em.getTransaction().commit(); // haendelt update implizit, kracht
    em.clear();
    emf.close();
}
```

Entity Booker properties:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer id; 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(nullable = false)
Date start;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(nullable = false)
Date end;   
@Column(nullable = false)
Integer courtNo;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) // Mueller S. 105, 109
@JoinColumn(name = "user")
User booker;
```

Entity User properties:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id; 
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String password; // TODO verschluesseln 
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;
```

Comment: Where does the booker come from? What's the code of the entities?

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, I added relevant parts!

Answer (score 0):

Many Things :
1 : the Fix
You don't need to write any CRUD method in jpa, EntityManager provides all required ones

```
public void updateBooking(Booking booking){
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.merge(booking);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
emf.close();
```

BUT

You shouldn't handle transaction this way, transaction should be opened in the service Layer not in the data access one. In fact, it should be managed by the container if you have one (means using Spring or Java EE server) using @transactional annotation.
If you absolutely want to manage it manually, you must handle eventual exception and rollback properly in case you meet one.  EntityManager and underlying transaction have generally the same scope/lifecycle.

Moreover you should have only one EntityManagerFactory for all the app.

Otherwise you don't need to specify fetch type here, a oneToOne association is always eagerly fetched.